# Does Android launcher activity always called?

Tags: android, android-activity

Does Android launcher activity (`android.intent.category.LAUNCHER`) always called. Or application could be started from another activity?

Currently I do some init stuff, like "current user loading", but sometimes i see that application crashed due to current user is null, which means that another activity was launched and launcher activity wasn't created before.

Comment: Can it be you have your custom Application object for your application and do something in Application.onCreate() which results in such behavior?

Comment: No Im not launching activities from application object

Comment: Perhaps you can post stacktrace from the DDMS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, application can be started from another activity. For example (I guess this is your scenario):

1. You normally start the application. Launcher activity is created, user's data is initialized, everything is ok and you are continuing working with your application - start other activities and so on.
2. You get incoming call and android kills your application because it need more memory to process the call.
3. Your call ends and you return to the application. Android restores activity stack this way: application#onCreate is invoked, your_last_visited_activity#onCreate is invoked. Launcher activity#onCreate was not invoked! So user's data is not initialized and you'll get NPE.

How to solve:

1. Initialize user's data in Application#onCreate to be able to continue working from any activity.

How to simulate android's kill:

1. Start your application and launch some activities.
2. Start task killer and kill your application (android do the same when it need more memory)
3. Return to your application (via e.g. recents). Android should restore activity task (see ActivityManager log traces in logcat)

Hope this helps.